# CSV write a list in a column

Tags: python, algorithm, csv

I am quite new to CSV writing with Python and I am not finding what I need so far. I am running an algorithm X times (let's say 10 but can be 100 or 1000), on an increasing number of entries, to gather some data. Precisely, I am doing the following:

- Step 1: Set the algorithm instance size
- Step 2: Run the algorithm X times and store the result of each run
- Step 3 : increase the instance size, go to step 2.

At the end of step 2, I have a list looking like this:

Number of messages exchanged for each iteration:
 
`[13.181238, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 13.181238, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 16.362476, 10.0]`

I would like to write this list in a csv file, as a column. Then, when I call the algorithm on a new instance, I want to append the new list as a new row of my CSV file, until everything is done.

The file could look like that:

```
Call 1      Call2       Call3  ... Call N
13.181238   20.0
10.0        23.181238
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think without knowing more, it sounds like you are just trying to execute your algorithm and then store the metadata related to the run, times, etc.  Yeah, totally doable.

Comment: Yes that just what I would like to do, its just to do some box plot on excel based on collected datas. But I didn't find anything about writing column by column, every time it looks quite long to do a "basic" operation like this one.

Comment: @Ecterion You can do this with `pandas` in a few lines. With the `csv` module though, I don't know how easy it'll be.

Comment: Adding a new column will require reading the entire existing csv file a row-at-a-time and adding the data for the column for that row. Since it's difficult to do this in-place, you'll need to write each modified row's data out to separate file. When the process is complete, you can then replace the original file with the new one. Depending on the file's size, it would be much faster to read the whole thing into memory, add the new column to all the rows, then overwrite the existing file.

Comment: When dealing with csv files, it's important to know whether you're using Python 2 or 3 because opening them is different in the two versions (if you're using the built-in `csv` module). Please add the appropriate language tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the CSV module supports write rows (because files in general are write line by line) here is a way for you to achieve that. Write all the information in a temporary file, so you don't have to keep in the memory, and when all the bench marking is done pivot the CSV file, thus transforming your rows to columns.

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
a = izip(*csv.reader(open("tempfile.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)
```

This will work without any problem if your file will feet in memory.

If you have to repeat this on a regular basis, and you want this to be quick, and you don't mind introducing a huge dependency, consider pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('tempfile.csv').T.to_csv('output.csv',header=False)
```

As a bonus you get the `T` operation - which does Transpose the underlying
Dataframe (created with `pd.read_csv('tempfile.csv')`).

Anything you can do with CSV in Python is better done with Pandas usually ...

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips, I didn't know pandas. I don't mind using some dependencies at all, so it is ok. I will try it.